# which methods are called when the phone is put to sleep versus minimized and then put to sleep in objective-c

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I'm writing an app that detects when you enter a specific location. When you reach a location, it detects the change and sends a local notification. When the notification is received and opened, it is supposed to switch screens. The app seemed to be working flawlessly for me, but my tester told me that the screen NEVER switches for him. To recreate the problem, we went to his house and he demonstrated. Something i noticed is that before entering the hotspot, he first hits the home button and then puts the phone to sleep. After performing multiple tests, we determined that the screens will switch if the phone was simply put to sleep with the app still open. If we minimize the app first AND THEN put the phone to sleep, the screens never switch.

The screen isn't supposed to switch until the app is opened with the notification. I'm curious as to what the difference is, if there's a delegate method to handle events like this, or why this could possibly be happening? any ideas?

**EDIT**

-- Code related to location services --

This is the singleton class i use for the location services

```
@implementation LocationManager

static LocationManager *locationManager;

+ (LocationManager *)locationManager {
    if (locationManager == NULL) {
        locationManager = [[LocationManager alloc] init];
    }

    return locationManager;
}

@end
```

This is the code in the welcomeviewcontroller that actually implements the delegate method (its long so im only posting the important parts)

```
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateLocations:(NSArray *)locations {
    if ([self getAppState] == TRACKING_HOTSPOT) {
        NSLog(@"\nLAT: %f\nLNG: %f", [self deviceLatitude], [self deviceLongitude]);
        for (int j = 0; j < [MinX count]; j++) {
            if ((([self deviceLatitude] > [MinX[j] floatValue] && [self deviceLatitude] < [MaxX[j] floatValue]) && ([self  deviceLongitude] > [MinY[j] floatValue] && [self deviceLongitude] < [MaxY[j] floatValue]))) {
                if ([self testCells: [CellId[j] intValue]]) {
                    [self.delegate setNum: [CellId[j] intValue]];
...
}
```

I also set the appropriate flags in the info.plist file. It was working on my last build, but i really havent changed much since then. I dont know why its not working. And, its only working in certain areas. It detects that it's in the hotspot, sends the notification to alert me that it went there, but when it switches view controllers it doesnt work ONLY if you hit the home button and then put the phone to sleep before receiving the notification. it switches correctly if the app is left open OR if you simply hit the home button. I watched memory and CPU management in Xcode through the process and memory drops through the floor when i minimize and put to sleep, but not when i simply put to sleep. I believe its possible the phone isnt considering it "in the background" until its minimized, even if the phone is asleep. Maybe im wrong.

In appdelegate, i set it up to detect whether it entered the foreground or not with flags. But no matter what, if the app is opened from a notification, it should send control to the didreceivelocalnotification method right?

Comment: How are you detecting the location? Show code.

Comment: singleton class, locationmanager, and the delegate is set to a class called WelcomeViewController. The delegate method handles a bunch of stuff. ill post it all in an edit above

Comment: Why aren't you using region monitoring of `CLLocationManager`?

Comment: you mean geofencing? we actually looked into that very deeply and decided not to go with it. This was the best suited for our purposes. although this is just a demo and eventually we might build geofencing into the final product. it depends on a lot of factors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you perform the switch in `– application:didReceiveLocalNotification:` Have you tried presenting local notification from `- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application`? [Here](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Chapters/IPhoneOSClientImp.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH103-SW1) is an example of implementation for local notification

Comment: yes thats correct, thats where im displaying code from. Also, the notification is sent when they enter a specific location, not when they enter the background